# Check if string contains number after specific word

Tags: java, regex, string, validation

can someone help me with string validation? I tried to find the solution, but none was satisfied.
I have the uri e.g. /dog/cat/house,1/mouse/bird,1/rabbit.

I need to check if after word (with comma) **bird,** there is a number or not. In my case sometimes i receive uri with number: "bird,1" and sometimes with word: "bird,foo".
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: `"bird,\\d+"` should do the trick.

Comment: In Java `\\bbird,(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)\\b` See https://regex101.com/r/kwqVYo/1

Comment: ^^ As per above, but instead `\\bbird,(?:1?[1-9]|[12]0)\\b` to save an alternation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `@Federico klez Culloca` and  `@The fourth bird` suggested you could use a regular expression (`\\bbird,(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|20)\\b`) but some security scans don't like regular expressions. In any case, one another (pure Java) solution would be:

*Updated the answer after user added more conditions.*

`would look for range 1, 2 .. 20 (01, 02 would return false).`

```
public static boolean isNumber() {
    // you can parametrize these 2
  String input = "/dog/cat/house,1/mouse/bird,10/rabbit.";
  String strOfInterest = "/bird,";

  boolean isStringEndingInLT20 = false;
  int indxOfInterest = input.indexOf("/bird,") + strOfInterest.length();
  char c1 = input.charAt(indxOfInterest);
  char c2 = input.charAt(indxOfInterest + 1);
  int i1 = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(indxOfInterest));

  if (Character.isDigit(c1) && Character.isDigit(c2)) {
    int num = Integer.parseInt("" + c1 + c2);
    if ((i1 > 0) && (num >= 1) && (i1 <= 20)) isStringEndingInLT20 = true;
  } else if (Character.isDigit(c1)) {
    if ((i1 >= 1) && (i1 <= 9)) isStringEndingInLT20 = true;
  }
  return isStringEndingInLT20;
}
```

NOTE: **I personally hate these verbose solutions and would prefer 1 line REGEX.  Try to avoid it and use regex. The only times I avoid regex is when it becomes performance bottleneck and/or causes a security concern.**

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mentioned I also need to check this number is in the range 1-20.

Comment: Modified the answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a practical algorithm, you can specify the keyword!
The premise is that the validity of the ***contains*** parameter is in line with your description.

> ***keyword***, (spaces are allowed)123/

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String contains = "/dog/cat/house,1/mouse/bird,a/rabbit";
    FreeTest f = new FreeTest();
    boolean has = f.hasNumber(contains, "bird");
    System.out.println(has);
}

/**
 * Check if string contains number after specific word
 *
 * @param contains string contains
 * @param key      the specific word (without comma)
 * @return yes or not
 */
public boolean hasNumber(String contains, String key) {
    int commaIndex = contains.indexOf(',', contains.indexOf(key));
    int startIndex = commaIndex + 1;
    boolean hasNumber = true;
    while (true) {
        char c = contains.charAt(startIndex++);
        if (c == '/') break; // exit
        if (c != ' ') {
            hasNumber = Character.isDigit(c);
        }
    }
    return hasNumber;
}
```